# Python: How to get rid of stdin lines in stdout

Tags: python, stdout, stdin

I have the following code where I want to put all of the folders in a specific directory into a list for a user to choose from.  Below I have a working solution, but my concern is that it may be possible for the stdout information to change, and I don't want to hardcode my list to ignore stdin information.

The line below `lineList = lineList[6:-3]` is my concern.

```
sshCommand = "plink root@255.255.255.255-pw PASSWORD"
lsCommand = "ls -1 --color=never -d */\nexit\n"
sshProcess = Popen(sshCommand,shell=False,stdin=PIPE,stdout=PIPE)
sshProcess.stdin.write("cd /mnt/PCAPS/GroupSetup\n")
sshProcess.stdin.write(lsCommand)
sshProcess.stdin.flush()
lineList = []
for line in sshProcess.stdout.readlines():
    line = line.replace("/","")
    line = line.strip('\n')
    line = line.strip('\r')
    lineList.append(str(line))

lineList = lineList[6:-3]
while(True):
    x = 0
    for line in lineList:
        x+=1
        print "(" + str(x) + ") " + line

    network_name = raw_input("Please select which network to use: ")

    try:
        network_name = lineList[int(network_name)-1]
        networkCorrect = raw_input('You have selected %s. Is this correct? (Y/N): ' %(network_name))
        if inputYNChecker(networkCorrect):
            return network_name
        else:
            print "\nPlease select a number listed above.\n"
    except:
        print "\nPlease select a number listed above.\n"
```

Which gives me the following output, which is what I want!

`Using username "root".
(1) A
(2) B
(3) C
(4) D
(5) E
(6) F`

However, when I do not have the `lineList = lineList[6:-3]` in my code, I get:

`Using username "root".
(1) Last login: Thu Dec  8 13:59:51 2016 from 255.255.255.255
(2) cd mntPCAPSGroupSetup
(3) ls -1 --color=never -d *
(4) exit
(5) ←]0;root@Test_Control:~[root@Test_Control ~]# cd mntPCAPSGroupSetup
(6) ←]0;root@Test_Control:mntPCAPSGroupSetup[root@Test_Control GroupSetup]# ls -1 --color=never -d *
(7) A
(8) B
(9) C
(10) D
(11) E
(12) F
(13) ←]0;root@Test_Control:mntPCAPSGroupSetup[root@Test_Control GroupSetup]# exit
(14) logout
(15) ←[H←[2J`

Is there a better way to get rid of the "garbage" return of stdout besides ignoring the specific lines?

Comment: is your code trying to find folders and files at a remote location or is your code on the same machine as the folder and files you are trying to get access too.

Comment: It connects to a remote server, goes to a specific directory, then lists all of the folders in that directory.  I changed the IP and folder names in my example above.

Comment: Maybe make a regex or other filter function to determine whether to print the line. `if should_print(line): print("( {} )".format(line))`

Comment: You could try adding a couple of `echo` commands with a special string you can use to mark the beginning and end of the list, then just search for those strings in the output.

Comment: Excellent idea Mark.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To eliminate the stdout info I did not want, I actually decided to use plink's -m feature which reads in a file as a bash.  I eliminated `stdin.write` commands. I now only have the following:

```
sshCommand = "plink root@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -pw PASSWORD -m getNetworkName.txt "
sshProcess = Popen(sshCommand,shell=False,stdin=PIPE,stdout=PIPE)
```

Where getNetworkName.txt contains:

```
cd /mnt/PCAPS/GroupSetup
ls -1 --color=never -d */
exit
```

which were the commands I was previously writing with `sshProcess.stdin.write()`

This in turn gives me a clean return of

```
(1) A
(2) B
(3) C
(4) D
(5) E
(6) F
```